# Checking the reason for segmentation fault on Linux server

Tags: c, linux

I have a Linux script written in C Language deployed at a remote server, to which multiple clients can connect. Due to some reason the script crashed and when I am trying to restart it I am getting segmentation fault.Is there any way by which I can Check at server side that what is stopping my script from starting, and is throwing  segmentation fault error.

Comment: Allow the server to create [*core dump*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump), then copy that and use together with a debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start out by enabling core dumps:

```
$ ulimit -c unlimited
```

Now run the script until it segfaults. This will create a core dump file in your working directory.

Next, use GDB (or any frontend of it) to debug it (note that you can copy the file to your local machine if you can't debug on the server):

```
$ gdb -c <core_file>
```

Don't forget to add the symbol file:

```
GDB> file my-prog
```

If it's easy to reproduce the problem, and provided you can debug directly on the server (with SSH or such), you can simply dive in and start the process with a debugger attached:

```
$ gdb my-prog
```

Comment: what is symbol file and what is its Use ?

Comment: @Asusgates It's a file that GDB uses to know the names of functions, variables, etc, at certain memory addresses referenced by the program.

Comment: @Asusgates Perhaps also important is to mention that it's best to compile your code with the `-g` GCC flag.

Comment: `GDB>` means inside the GDB shell, which you run with the command `gdb`